# Can someone make me clear about the actual register values after mov w0, #0 vs mov x0, #0?

Tags: arm, reverse-engineering

I'm new to ARM64 assembly. 
Can someone make me clear about the actual register values after `mov w0, #0` vs `mov x0, #0`?

Comment: What do the documents say? What have you checked so far?

Comment: To everyone else, this is a very, very obvious thing. So in order to have any help, you need to tell us what you think and what is confusing. It also helps to know _what_ you are using as a reference, since the canonical reference, the ARM Architecture manual is pretty clear (and, no, I won't copy paste that part for you here, it doesn't make for a useful question in this form)

Answer (score 1):

Well this one really requires some home work on your side but there exists different situations for everyone, after all telling google what you want is also an art which is learned with time, so I am going to point you to some stuff that you must read yourself

Google "ARMv8 registers" open the first link starting with **Chapter 4. ARMv8 Registers - infocenter ARM**. study that and you will know whats the difference.